# Python: add the key to each list item, and then convert to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
```

I have hard coded keys `['one','two','three','four','five']`

and I want the dictionary like

```
{'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4, 'five':None}
```

Keys are always more than the number of items in list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import itertools

lst = [1,2,3,4]
lst2 = ['one','two','three','four','five']

print dict(itertools.izip_longest(lst2, lst, fillvalue=None))
# {'five': None, 'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'three': 3, 'two': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways to do it

```
>>> K=['one','two','three','four','five']
>>> V=[1,2,3,4]
>>> dict(map(None, K, V))
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'five': None, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}



>>> D=dict.fromkeys(K)
>>> D.update(zip(K,V))
>>> D
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'five': None, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Comment: for the first example you can just do :`dict(map(None, K, V))`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dict(zip(keys, lst + [None]*(len(keys)-len(lst))))
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'five': None, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```